# Why java multicast receiver not able to receive packets on Windows XP?

Tags: java, windows, sockets, multicast

I have a MulticastReceiver and MulticastSender in java on ip 224.2.2.3 and port 8888. When I run receiver on windows XP, I am not able to receive the packets. All my linux receivers are receiving the packets as expected. Things are also fine, when my sender is on windows.

- I have turned off firewall on XP.
- I have bound the interface to my socket on which I expect to arrive the packet.
- I have all the machine on same network.

Is there anything else that needs tweaking?

Comment: Try binding the socket to 0.0.0.0.

Comment: Binding to 0.0.0.0 also did not help.

Comment: @EJP I must have tried something wrong. Changing the receiver to 0.0.0.0 indeed help. Please post that as answered I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: When running sender on machines with VMWare/Virtualbox, I had to bind the sender socket as well to appropriate interface. All combinations are working fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the socket to 0.0.0.0 so it can receive multicasts via all interfaces. You may also have to *join* the group via all interfaces.

Binding to the multicast address itself seems to be a Linux-ism. It doesn't work on Windows.

Comment: In fact my observation about 0.0.0.0 is different. On windows XP, binding to 0.0.0.0 works with jdk 6. On ubuntu I tried with Openjdk 7, it did not work. On Win 7, I tried with jdk 6 it did not work. Finally I resorted to binding to user supplied IP.

Comment: @ManishSapariya Binding a socket to 0.0.0.0 works on every platform known to man. You will have to further define 'does not work'.

Answer (score 4):

If your receiver has multiple network cards (eg. VirtualBox installed) reduce the priority of the second Ethernet card.

> Start -> Control Panel -> Network Settings -> Change adapter settings -> Internet Protocol Properties -> Advanced -> Uncheck Automatic Metric and give a high value (eg. 800)

Answer (score 0):

I use multicast socket senders on windows 2008 server and receivers as different network devices including PCs. However, never came across the challenge to use 0.0.0.0 on a windows 7 professional (not sure about XP). I use a 226.x.x.x address. Most of the 224.x.x.x addresses are occupied with IP Multicast space registry (not sure if XP has disallowed them), which by default I have seen doesnt work for multicast receivers. Your port number seems fine, fitting the allowed range.